# SVM and support vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, machine-learning

I had gone through several example of [support vector machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) (SVM) and I see one starts explaining SVM by picking up the support vectors upfront (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NxnPkZM9bc)). Basically, those vectors that fall on the decision boundaries are picked up upfront. As I was new to SVM, I was wondering how would a machine do this. What is the mechanism used, is the Euclidean distance between two points (vectors) the key?

Comment: Ignore the word "machine", it means nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Bacically, SVM amounts to having a computer numerically solve an optimization problem.  SVM, in its standard form, boils down to a quadratic programming (QP) problem, which has many desirable features which make it easy to solve including convexity and a linear gradient.  There are several codes out there to solve SVMs such as libsvm which you can download and use.